# Programmatically setting constraints not working for my table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have these constraints in place for my UItableView (from storyboard):

```
musicHomeTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
musicHomeTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor ).isActive = true
musicHomeTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainTabBar.topAnchor).isActive = true
musicHomeTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
```

The above code is called from `viewDidLoad` and it works fine. Yet when I try to execute this code later:

```
musicHomeTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Nothing happens. `mainTabBar` and `playerView` are both programmatically setUp views and subviews of view.

I've tried `view.layoutSubviews()` and `view.layOutIfNeeded()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`musicHomeTableView` already has a `bottomAnchor` constraint. You need to remove this constraint before adding another one to the same anchor. Setting another constraint to the same anchor does not remove the old constraint.

```
class ViewController {
   var musicHomeTableViewBottomAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

   func viewDidLoad() {
      musicHomeTableViewBottomAnchorConstraint = musicHomeTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
      musicHomeTableViewBottomAnchorConstraint!.isActive = true
   }

   func addNewConstraint() {
     if let constraint = musicHomeTableViewBottomAnchorConstraint {
        constraint.isActive = false
     }
     // Add new constraint here
   }
}
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is one.